# How to use jena ontology api on android?

Tags: java, android, maven, jena, ontology

I am new at this area. I have built an ontology project on eclipse by using jena.
However, I would like to use it on Android. I have found the androidjena, and follow the instruction [here](https://github.com/sbrunk/jena-android)
My android app's minSdkVersion 21.
I download the Jena modules and put then in D:\myproject.gradle

After I add this on build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        MavenLocal()
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'mobi.seus.jena:jena-android-arq:2.13.0'
}
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Then I synced the project, here comes an error

```
Could not find method MavenLocal() for arguments [] on repository container
```

Did I missed anything ? or I put the Jena modules to the wrong place?
Please help found out what the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1 - According to the instruction on the page you linked to, you should add `MavenLocal()` to the `repositories` section of the `build.gradle` file.  You don't appear to have done that.

**CORRECTION** - according to the example in the [Gradle manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.pdf) on page 460<sup>1</sup> it should be `mavenLocal()`.  I think that Gradle is case sensitive.  If it is, then the Jena instructions are at fault.

Problem #2 - And according to the instructions it is supposed to say "compile" ... but I gather that changed in gradle 3.0

Problem #3 - The instructions also say:

> Currently the artifacts are not deployed to a public repository. If you want to use them in a team you should deploy them to your own Maven repository or add the jars as unmanaged dependencies.

Have you done that?  Or have you done the following instead?

> Create modified Jena packages:
>
> ```
> $ cd jena-android
> $ mvn install
> ```
>
> This will install modified Jena packages that run on Android into your
>   local Maven repository.

The point is that you can't just tell Maven / Gradle to pull the Jena artifacts from a public Maven repo.  The artifacts must be built and installed into your local repo and (if you are working in a team) pushed to your (typically private) team repo.

---

<sup>1 - ... or search for "Using init script to perform extra configuration before projects are evaluated".</sup>

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have done that, but it occur the error I mention above.

Comment: the problem2 is because I'm using gradle:3.0.It replace compile with implementation. and I did the following (create the jena package)

Comment: The problem 2 is still a problem (maybe).  "implementation" and "implementaion" are not the same thing.   Look carefully ....